# Inverse of function defined by Integral

Tags: integral-equations, inverse-function

I was working today in the equation of a pendulum:
What I got is 
$$t = f (\theta)=k\cdot \int_0^\theta {\frac{du}{\sqrt {\cos u}}}$$
Where $k $ is a constant.

I know that this function has an inverse, but I didn't know how to find that inverse.

Can you please help me to do that?

(
If it is not possible to express it as a closed form expression or as an integral, can you at least express it as an infinite serie?)

Comment: This function is essentially an incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind, and the inverse function is called the amplitude for (Jacobi) elliptic functions. That might or might not be satisfying for you: these functions don't have more elementary definitions. You can certainly, in principle, find the Maclaurin series for $\frac1{\sqrt{\cos u}}$, integrate term-by-term to get the Maclaurin series for $f(\theta)$, and then find the inverse of that power series.